# How to fix binary trees coming back with "cannot read 'left' of null' after running test?

Tags: javascript, tree, binary

My unit tests for my binary tree and binary search tree are coming back as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null.

I've looked at similar questions here and have checked for capitalization errors, indenting errors, ran npm run lint to check for any linter errors. My unit test is coming back as a TypeError(which are usually obvious to fix) and I am at a loss as to why it thinks property 'left' of null is unreadable. I do not see any scoping issues and am at a loss. Where would you suggest I direct my attention to next?

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinaryTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  preOrder() {
    let results = [];

    let _walk = node => {

      results.push(node);

      if(node.left) _walk(node.left);

      if(node.right) _walk(node.right);

    };

    _walk(this.root);

    return results;
  }
};
```

I am expecting this to return a collection from a preorder traversal but it throws

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null

on the `if(node.left)` within the `_walk` function.

Comment: What language is this? Looks like `node` is null to me from the error you are getting.

Comment: This is JavaScript. If I try results.push(node.value) it cannot find value and then cannot find left. If I pass in value as a parameter in the constructor and assign value to this.root, then I fail my instantiation of a tree test.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `this.root` is `null` (i.e., when the tree is empty). The solution is to put the `null` test at the very start of your recursive function:

```
let _walk = node => {
  if (!node) return; // <--- here
  results.push(node.value);
  _walk(node.left); // <--- not here
  _walk(node.right);
};
```